# Combo box mouse wheel scrolling also scrolling on page

Tags: combobox, scroll

I have a dojo comboBox element which I fill with a lot of entries so the combo-box becomes scrollable. When I scroll inside the combobox with the mouse wheel also the page is being scrolled. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dojo.connect(combo, 'onChange', function() {

        var dropDownMenu = combo.dropDown.domNode;

        if (dropDownMenu !== null) {
            dropDownMenu.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event) {
              document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            },false);
        }
    });
```